# Start emacs-gdb from command line?

Tags: shell, emacs, gdb

I like emacs's gdb mode a lot better than GDB's command line or TUI modes, but there are some programs that want a "debugger command line" program that it can take and run in an environment it sets up.

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to make emacs pop up in gdb mode using a command line substitute for gdb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your .bashrc:

> gdbtool () { emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb
>   --annotate=3 $*\")";}

Then you can run "gdbtool programToDebug"

Source: http://www.inet.net.nz/~nickrob/

Comment: Great! Do you happen to know how to pass it arguments to run with as well? I started a gist: https://gist.github.com/971442

Comment: Is there such a way to start gdb?  I would start it as given in the answer, then, pass the program's command line arguments to gdb's `run` command.  Or, sometimes use `set args` and then simply do `run`.

Comment: @cdleary:  gdbtool() { emacs --eval "(gdb --annotate=3; --args $* \")";}

Comment: And just pass arguments after your program name as if you were running your program. Like "gdbtool foo 1 2 3 blah blah"

Comment: And if you are running a more modern emacs/gdb and/or are getting funny output at the start, try "-i=mi" instead of older "--annotate=3".