# launching emacs-gdb from the command line part 2

Tags: emacs, gdb, zsh

I want to launch emacs with gdb running.  I'd like to have all of the command line arguments fed in at the same time.  This post:
[Start emacs-gdb from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997309/start-emacs-gdb-from-command-line), already solves 95% of the problem, but I have an annoying nagging follow-on to the problem.  I really need to be able to pass in arguments that have spaces, something ala

```
edbg path/to/myprog --firstarg "something with spaces" --secondarg 1
```

I've been searching on this site and on google, and I played around for a couple of hours, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand it you have this Bash function defined:

```
edbg() { emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb --annotate=3 $*\")";}
```

and it doesn't work because any spaces in the arguments get reparsed into new word boundaries. Well, this is a common enough problem in Bash scripts that there's a special variable $@ that expands the arguments to the function differently when it's inside a double-quoted string. This gets us half-way there. The rest is just putting the quotes back around them:

```
edbg() {
  arglist="";
  for a in "$@"; do
    if [[ $a == ${a/ /} ]]; then
      arglist="$arglist $a";
    else
      arglist="$arglist \\\"$a\\\"";
    fi
  done;
  emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb --annotate $arglist\")"
}
```

Note that this won't put quotes around args that contain tabs or newlines which would also require quotes; your $IFS may vary.

Comment: Thanks db48x.  This took me where I needed to go.  To help others, if you patch up the above with the following line, the example should completely work as expected:  emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb --annotate=3; -cd `pwd` --args $arglist\")"